# How to convert a varchar(50) into DateTime in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a column of data that's `varchar(50)`.  A sample data point reads "31-Dec-2001".
Is it possible to convert this into `DateTime`?  I use SQL Server 2008.  Thanks.

Comment: Does all the rows have the same date format?

Comment: yes all the rows in the varchar(50) column have the same format.  I'd like to convert all of the rows in this column into DateTime format.

Comment: @marc_s - They are trying to fix the issue now by the looks of things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE T
(
X VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO T VALUES ('31-Dec-2001');

SET LANGUAGE ENGLISH;

ALTER TABLE T ALTER COLUMN X DATETIME NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is!!

```
select convert(datetime,'31-Dec-2001')
```

Comment: I have a column called "varchardate" which contains the data to be reformatted.  I want to convert everything in that column into datetime format, as opposed to just one data point.  How do I do this?

Comment: @phan `ALTER TABLE YourTable ALTER COLUMN YourColumn DATETIME [NOT] NULL`

Comment: @phan: What you need, do you need to change the column data type or select all the data to somewhere in `datetime` format?

Comment: I just need to change the column's date type.  Thank you HD!

Comment: @phan: Then you shoud do what Martin said !! Alter the column data type

Comment: HD, Are you sure you need brackets around [NOT]?

Comment: @phan - Square brackets in syntax indicate that is optional. You use `NULL` or `NOT NULL` dependant on what is actually required.

Comment: @phan:No not necessary `ALTER TABLE TableName ALTER COLUMN ColName DATETIME NOT NULL` should work. `Not Null` also can be optional depends on your requirement

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following :

```
select cast('31-Dec-2001' as datetime)
```

But you should note that without time part being provided in the string literal, after conversion, the time part of the date will be midnight: `00:00:00`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
select convert(datetime,'31-Dec-2001',1)
```

Comment: Why you passing 1 for?